# How to combine columns in sql based on another field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table in SQL Server 2008 R2 like this:

```
Acc_id  Bench-1     Bench-2
-------------------------------
  1      xx 
  1                   vv
  2      pp 
  2                   ii
  3      kk 
  4                   ll
```

Now, I want to combine this table on the basis of `Acc_id` column and get something like:

```
Acc_id   Bench-1     Bench-2
---------------------------------
  1       xx            vv
  2       pp            ii
  3       kk    
  4                     ll
```

So, could someone please help me out.

Comment: The phrase you're looking for is `JOIN`.

Comment: can you please explain how to use it in my case

Comment: You're going to need a full outer join as you want to show nulls from both tables

Answer (score 0):

I would do this like:

```
select 
  Acc_id, 
  max([Bench-1)] as [Bench-1], 
  max(([Bench-2]) as [Bench-2]
from 
  myTable
group by 
  Acc_id
```

This assumes Acc_id won't have multiple rows with data in the same columns

If that is the case then your knowledge of the use of the results will come into play.  I often will perform this more completely like

```
select 
  Acc_id, 
  min([Bench-1)] as [Bench-1Min], 
  max([Bench-1)] as [Bench-1Max], 
  Count([Bench-1)] as [Bench-1Count], 
  min([Bench-2)] as [Bench-2Min], 
  max([Bench-2)] as [Bench-2Max], 
  Count([Bench-2)] as [Bench-2Count], 
from 
  myTable
group by 
  Acc_id
```

All this depends on the actual complexity of the real data and what you want to do with the results.  If it IS actually as simple as you example the multi-join solution may work for you, but I often find that in more complex summarizations the group by solution give me results and performance I need.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but can you please tell the significance of using max() function here.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT ISNULL(b1.Acc_id,b2.Acc_id) as Acc_id,
        b1.data,
        b2.data

 FROM Bench-1 AS b1 FULL OUTER JOIN
      Bench-2 AS b2 ON b2.Acc_id = b1.Acc_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Check Below query

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.acc_id,
            b.bench_1,
            c.bench_2
FROM   table1 a
   LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT acc_id,
                           bench_1
                    FROM   table1
                    WHERE  Isnull(bench_1, '') <> '') b
                ON a.acc_id = b.acc_id
   LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT acc_id,
                           bench_2
                    FROM   table1
                    WHERE  Isnull(bench_2, '') <> '') c
                ON a.acc_id = c.acc_id
```